# fgrep matching literal "*"

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to clean my logs files from lines than contain some strings. The strings are in a file and made up of random [keyboard] chars [yes also *, + etc]
Seems like grep does an exact matching of * :

```
grep "abc*" logs :gives a matchine line
blah_blah """abc*""" duh_duh 

However when I read it off the file it doesnt work with fgrep:
cat file:
"abc*"
fgrep -f file logs => Matches nothing
```

I thought fgrep is same as grep + f [grep -f] . Is there some flag I can use with fgrep to make this happen ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`fgrep` is equivalent to `grep -F`, not `grep -f`.  And the `-F` option matches fixed strings, not patterns.  If you're trying to match the literal string "abc*", that's different from a regexp starting with "ab" and followed by zero or more "c" characters.

Let's establish what we're working with:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat logs.txt 
ab
blah_blah """abc*""" duh_duh
abc
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat patterns.txt 
abc*
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

And try both grep and fgrep:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ grep -f patterns.txt logs.txt 
ab
blah_blah """abc*""" duh_duh
abc
[ghoti@pc ~]$ fgrep -f patterns.txt logs.txt 
blah_blah """abc*""" duh_duh
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

As you can see, the pattern is interpreted as a regular expression by `grep`, but as a literal string by `fgrep`.

Confirm whether you're matching *strings* or *patterns*, and you'll know which version of grep you should use.

Answer (score 0):

What version of `grep` do you use? This probably may be a bug which was fixed in recent versions, because all works fine for me:

```
$ cat logs.txt
blah_blah """abc*""" duh_duh
$ cat patterns.txt
"abc*"
$ fgrep -f patterns.txt logs.txt
blah_blah """abc*""" duh_duh
$ fgrep --version
GNU grep 2.6.3
```